# simple animation with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, stochastic-process

I am trying to make a simple animation for a stochastic process (just black and white dots randomly changing their colors). To simulate that, I have basically plotted the dots over a grid. However, the important parameter for me being the rate of black dots, I'd like to draw under this grid a progressive bar showing the rate #blackdots/#totaldots looking approximately like this : [///////////////////////_____] 70% (simply just like a power charge bar).

I tried this but the bars are overlaid, and I don't think that Slider is meant to do such animations.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

t=1500
d=5
n=10
raws = [i for i in range(n)]

config = [[2*random.randrange(2)-1 for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

def color(op):
    if op == 1:
        return 'white'
    return 'black'

nbblack = 0
for i in config:
  for j in i :
     nbblack += (j==-1)

blackrate = nbblack/(n**2)

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

for line in range(n):
    colors = [color(config[line][raw]) for raw in raws]
    plt.scatter([line]*n,raws,c=colors,edgecolors='black',s=50)

plt.title('t=0',fontdict={'size': 16},x=-0.20,y=25)

samp = Slider(axamp, 'Rate', 0, 1, valinit=blackrate,color='black')

for step in range(t):

    plt.pause(0.001)

    xpick = random.randrange(n)
    ypick = random.randrange(n)
    opinion_picked = config[xpick][ypick]
    for j in range(d) :
        neighboor = random.randrange(n),random.randrange(n)
        opinion_neig = config[neighboor[0]][neighboor[1]]
        if opinion_neig == opinion_picked :
            break

        elif j == d-1 :
            config[xpick][ypick]=-config[xpick][ypick]
            nbblack-=config[xpick][ypick]
            blackrate = nbblack/(n**2)
            plt.title('t={}'.format(step),fontdict={'size': 16},x=-0.20,y=25)
            for line in range(n):
               colors = [color(config[line][raw]) for raw in raws]
               plt.scatter([line]*n,raws,c=colors,edgecolors='black',s=50)

            axamp = plt.axes([0.28, 0.15, 0.48, 0.03])

            samp = Slider(axamp, 'Rate', 0, 1, valinit=blackrate,color='black')

plt.show()
```

I am not very familiar with maplot so please let me know if there is a better way to do things and thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: `but the bars are overlaid` ??? what does that mean.  You should include **all** imports in your [mre]. - `NameError: name 'Slider' is not defined`

Comment: Thank you, I modified the code and I mean that at each step of the loop the new bar is drawn above the old ones resulting in something unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think that Slider is meant to do such animations ... please let me know if there is a better way to do things ...

Maybe using a custom colorbar would work. I adapted from the [Discrete Intervals colorbar example](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#discrete-intervals-colorbar).

The following uses the percentage of *black* dots to decide which portion of the color bar should be black or white.

Here is an example without animation: five successive plots drawn by a loop.  I tried to keep it as close to your example as possible.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

t = 1500
d = 5
n = 10
raws = [i for i in range(n)]


def f(t=t, d=d, n=n, raws=raws):

    # try to get more skew in the data
    mode = random.random()
    config = [[random.triangular(mode=mode) > 0.5 for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
    config = [[int(item) or -1 for item in row] for row in config]
    # config = [[2*random.randrange(2)-1 for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

    def color(op):
        if op == 1:
            return "white"
        return "black"

    nbblack = 0
    for i in config:
        for j in i:
            nbblack += j == -1

    blackrate = nbblack / (n ** 2)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
    # plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

    for line in range(n):
        colors = [color(config[line][raw]) for raw in raws]
        plt.scatter([line] * n, raws, c=colors, edgecolors="black", s=50)

    plt.title("t=0", fontdict={"size": 16}, x=-0.20, y=25)

    cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(["black", "white"])
    bounds = [0, int(blackrate * 100), 100]
    norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
    fig.colorbar(
        mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
        # cax=ax,
        # boundaries=[0] + bounds + [13],  # Adding values for extensions.
        # extend='both',
        ticks=bounds,
        spacing="proportional",
        orientation="horizontal",
        label="Percentage Black",
    )

    plt.show()
    plt.close()


for _ in range(5):
    f()
```

---

[BoundaryNorm](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm.html) determines how the colors are distributed. The example uses two colors, black/white, and defines two bins between 0 and 100 using the percentage of black dots for the *bin edge*.

The `spacing="proportional"` argument to [Figure.colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar) ensures the black/white area is proportional to the bins.

---

[image: Example plot]

---

The [Matplotlib Tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html) are worth investing time in.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot that really helped me!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please [consider accepting it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)